# How can I get the value of a specific key in a map?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So lets say I have a map

```
let queue = new Map()
queue.set("the key", "the value")
```

now if I have the key how do get the values which are assigned to the key?
this is a genuine doubt I have tried queue.get("the key") but it doesnt seem to work

Ok my bad I forgot to mention some important details, I have exported the queue and imported it to anoter file with module.exports and require()

```
module.exports.Words = (queue)
```

and then in the second file

```
let Something = require("../File1")
value = Something.Words.get("the key") 

console.log(value)
```

This console.log gives the error:
value = Something.Words.get('the key')
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: Yes, it _does_ work. See the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mre].

Comment: [`queue.get('the key')` does work](https://jsfiddle.net/venokmz4/).

Comment: @SebastianSimon I am sorry for the confusion I forgot to give the details and I have updated the code now

Comment: @Andy I am sorry for the confusion I forgot to give the details and I have updated the code now

Comment: @SebastianSimon sorry it was a typing mistake I have re editted it now and I still get the error

Comment: Given the implied file structure, the error is not reproducible. You have two files, one of which is inside one directory (let’s call it `main.js`), the other one is called either `File1` or `File1.js` and is outside the directory. When calling `main.js` with `node`, the code you’ve provided produces the desired result. Unless you’re requiring the wrong file or forgot to save, this error will never show.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I have made sure that the files that I am importing are right and that I have saved them but this error still pops up :(

Comment: dou want to do this with object or it should be Map?\

Comment: It should be a map because later on in the second file i need to get the values for the specific key @mohammadNaimi

Comment: @Zen I’ve copy-pasted your code twice, literally. It worked both times. Again, [edit] your post and show us a [mre]; _reproducible_ in the sense that anyone could copy-paste the code you’ll show, do any necessary configurations, and then get the exact error that you’re getting.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I have added the actual code

Comment: Well @SebastianSimon what do you think?

Answer (score -2):

Please see the working example below:

```js
 let queue = new Map();
 queue.set('the key', 'the value');
 alert(queue.get('the key'));
```